# javascript horizontal scroll with buttons

Tags: javascript, css

On mu profile pages I have a small div where I display awards for doing different things. to save space the div is really small but I was gone have a horizontal scroll using buttons.

```
<div class="award-wrapper fr" style="width:19%; margin:auto;">
    <h3 class="award-title"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Awards</h3>
    <div class="award-content" id="inner outer" style=" margin:0 auto; text-align:center;">
        <div style="float:left; height:100%; left:0; position:absolute;">
           <input type="button" value="«" class="scroll_button" id="left-button"/>
        </div>

        <div id="myDiv" style="float: left;">
           <?php include"award.php"; ?>
        </div>

        <div style="float:right; height:100%; right:0; position:absolute;">
           <input type="button" value="»" class="scroll_button" id="right-button"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.scroll_button {
    opacity: 0.5;
    color:#fff;
    padding:3px;
    height:100%;
}

.scroll_button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    color:#05c7f7;
}

.scroll_button:active {
    color:#05c7f7;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background:#08090a;
}
```

not sure if any other parts of my code is necessary

Comment: Can you create a code snippet and include the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean having a left button to force the scrollbar left, and a similiar right to force it right, it's definitely so plausible.

https://jsfiddle.net/5ug583ff/

```
var button = document.getElementById('slide');
button.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
};
```

Code example found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

I am not 100% sure if this is the answer to your question as I didn't fully understand your question.

Comment: nope, wasnt able to get it to work, but heres a picture + where each div goes (not sure if it helps) http://imgur.com/a/ucPLr

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow horizontal scrolling in your awards div...

Replace this:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="float: left;">
<?php include"award.php"; ?>
</div>
```

With this:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="float: left; overflow-x:scroll;">
    <?php include"award.php"; ?>
</div>
```